# Add a vertical line marker to Google Visualization's LineChart that moves when mouse move?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Is it possible to display a vertical Line marker showing the current x-axis value on LineChart, and moving when mouse moves ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While this was difficult before, a recent update to the API makes it much easier!  You need to use a mouseover event handler to get the mouse coordinates and the new ChartLayoutInterface to translate the coordinates into chart values.  Here's some example code:

**[edit - fixed cross-browser compatibility issue]**
**[edit - updated to get the value of points near the annotation line]**

```
function drawChart() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'x');
    // add an "annotation" role column to the domain column
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
    data.addColumn('number', 'y');

    // add 100 rows of pseudorandom data
    var y = 50;
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        y += Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) * Math.pow(-1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 2));
        data.addRow([i, null, y]);
    }
    // add a blank row to the end of the DataTable to hold the annotations
    data.addRow([null, null, null]);
    // get the index of the row used for the annotations
    var annotationRowIndex = data.getNumberOfRows() - 1;

    var options = {
        annotation: {
            1: {
                // set the style of the domain column annotations to "line"
                style: 'line'
            }
        },
        height: 400,
        width: 600
    };

    // create the chart
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    // create 'ready' event listener to add mousemove event listener to the chart
    var runOnce = google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        google.visualization.events.removeListener(runOnce);
        // create mousemove event listener in the chart's container
        // I use jQuery, but you can use whatever works best for you
        $('#chart_div').mousemove(function (e) {
            var xPos = e.pageX - container.offsetLeft;
            var yPos = e.pageY - container.offsetTop;
            var cli = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
            var xBounds = cli.getBoundingBox('hAxis#0#gridline');
            var yBounds = cli.getBoundingBox('vAxis#0#gridline');

            // is the mouse inside the chart area?
            if (
                (xPos >= xBounds.left || xPos <= xBounds.left + xBounds.width) &&
                (yPos >= yBounds.top || yPos <= yBounds.top + yBounds.height) 
            ) {
                // if so, draw the vertical line here
                // get the x-axis value at these coordinates
                var xVal = cli.getHAxisValue(xPos);
                // set the x-axis value of the annotation
                data.setValue(annotationRowIndex, 0, xVal);
                // set the value to display on the line, this could be any value you want
                data.setValue(annotationRowIndex, 1, xVal.toFixed(2));

                // get the data value (if any) at the line
                // truncating xVal to one decimal place,
                // since it is unlikely to find an annotation like that aligns precisely with the data
                var rows = data.getFilteredRows([{column: 0, value: parseFloat(xVal.toFixed(1))}]);
                if (rows.length) {
                    var value = data.getValue(rows[0], 2);
                    // do something with value
                }

                // draw the chart with the new annotation
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }
        });
    });

    // draw the chart
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/tVCv9/12

Comment: is there any way to find annotation value as string on mouse over ? in http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/tVCv9/ i want to get value of text which is displayed on  moving line. I want to alert that value.

Comment: In this example, the annotation value is created on the fly, so you don't have to do anything special to get it - it's already available to the mouseover code (on this line: `data.setValue(annotationRowIndex, 1, xVal.toFixed(2));`).  FYI, I updated the jsfiddle to correct a cross-browser compatibility issue.

Comment: Is it possible to have a single line which will move with mouse over on two line charts and display data (annotation) accordingly?

Comment: Yes, you just need to modify the event listener to add an annotation to the second chart, then use the same listener function on both chart container divs.

Comment: It would be a great help if you can provide me some code for how to do it? as i dont know how to add annotation to second chart from first chart's listener.

Comment: how to find intersection point of vertical line with plotted graph(blue line)?

Comment: Are you looking to find the value when it intersects with a data point on the line, or do you want to get an interpolated value if it falls between two points?

Comment: I am trying to  find the value when it intersects with a data point on the line.

Comment: FYI, due to the way in which we calculate the position of the mouse along the axis, it is extremely unlikely that the annotation line will align perfectly with a data point, so I wrote the code to find points that are close to the annotation line.  You can also adjust the precision of the line to make it more likely that the line with align with points (assuming your data points lie on some predictable interval).

Comment: is there any other approach which is more accurate than this for finding data intersection point with line?

Comment: You can trade off the accuracy of the position of the annotation line for accuracy of the intersection with data points.

Comment: How to find intersection point of vertical moving line with chart plotted if i am using datetime on x axis?

Comment: The solution looks smart, but is not smooth. I tried this code with graph containing 1474 points and it is extremely slow (core i7) to draw the graph on every mousemove event. Is there any more effective way how to update the annotation position? The original graph renders very smooth despite there was kind of mousemove when hovering over lines.

Comment: Since I wrote this, many of the charts (including LineCharts) have a new `crosshair` option that handles this functionality in a more elegant and performant way. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/crosshairs